# Unable to start zookeeper (Last transaction was partial)

Tags: apache-zookeeper

While I am trying to start zookeeper I am getting below error

```
[2017-05-24 11:52:31,633] ERROR Last transaction was partial. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.Util)
[2017-05-24 11:52:31,634] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileHeader.deserialize(FileHeader.java:64)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.inStreamCreated(FileTxnLog.java:585)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.createInputArchive(FileTxnLog.java:604)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.goToNextLog(FileTxnLog.java:570)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.next(FileTxnLog.java:652)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:158)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.loadData(ZooKeeperServer.java:283)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.startdata(ZooKeeperServer.java:410)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.startup(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:119)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:87)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:53)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
```

Could you please help me with this fix.

Thank you.

Comment: seems that your `TxnLog` is broken, is that one node of your cluster or a standalone node ?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217654/how-to-recover-zookeeper-from-java-io-eofexception-after-a-server-crash , but I couldn't seem to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when the snapshots in zookeeper dataDir is corrupt.
you can fix this by cleanup the contents of dataDir and restart zookeeper